# Apply different font to a same label

Tags: c#, asp.net

My website is in two languages, English and Japanese. All the text is coming from a database (table fields are id, labelname, labeltextenglish, labeltextjapanese) depending on the selected language.

Below is my code to display the label text (ENQUIRY) which is coming from database.

```xml
<div class="row" style="padding-left: 10px;"> 
    <b id="EnquiryHeading" style="font-family: Mumsies">ENQUIRY</b> 
</div>
```

My requirement is to show this text in a specific japanese font if the user selects japanese language.

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you provide this font as a web-font or is it expected to be installed on the client? (afaik it's not a standard font)

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to set the font family according to the selected language on page load.

```
function SetFontFamily(element, language) {
    if(language == 'japanese')
    {
        element.style.fontFamily = 'Mumsies';
    }
    else
    {
        element.style.fontFamily = 'Something else';
    }
}
```

You would have to call the message for every element that can display text out of the database. 
You can provide a css class to such elements and select them easily using jquery:

```
var elements = $(".CSSClass");
```